Make zero and plus sign same size inside subscript in math mode
I want to make plus and zero sign equal size to make the following picture symmetric;
for instance, to align with respect to the plus sign but without using && or something like that.
Here's the the code used to generate the image below:
\begin{align}
&a_0\epsilon_0+b_0\\
&a_+\epsilon_++b_+
\end{align}


I tried putting {} around the plus sign, but it does not achieve my purpose.
Here is what I want to do. I manipulated the pdf output in Inkscape; the width of the plus sign is equal to the with of 0.


Does a^{}_{0}\epsilon^{}_{0} (instead of a_{0}\epsilon_{0}) look like what're you're looking for?

@Mico, thank you for your response, but no. Is there a way to suspend the question before I get time to use inkscape to show what I want? I'll add the outcome I want.

By "the same size", should we assume you mean "the same width"?  The plus sign is as wide as it is tall, while the zero is narrower.  You might try b_{\text{\scriptscriptstyle$+$}}.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "suspend the question"?

@Mico, nevermind. I meant something like remove the question while I improve it a bit to avoid downvotes or being closed.

No worries. I've provided an upvote in the meantime. :-)

I'm not sure it's a good idea, but you're the judge.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\subplus}{{%
  \resizebox{\fontcharwd\scriptfont0`0}{!}{$\scriptstyle+$}%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
a_0\epsilon_0+b_0 \\
a_\subplus\epsilon_\subplus+b_\subplus
\end{gather*}

\end{document}


The idea is to scale the symbol to have the same width as a subscript 0.

By default, TeX renders first-level subscript (and superscript) material in \scriptstyle, with a 30% reduction in font size, while second-level subscript (and superscript) material gets rendered at an additional 30% font size reduction, aka \scriptscriptstyle, for a total reduction of ca 50%. (0.7*0.7=0.49\approx 0.5.)
I think your query may be rephrased as "How do I render material in first-level subscripts at a font size that's appropriate for second-level subscript material?" The answer is: issue the instruction \scriptscriptstyle at the start of the material in question.

If your document contains many instances of _{\scriptscriptstyle+}, you may want to provide a shortcut macro, say, \sspl, as is done in the following sample code.
\documentclass{article} 
\let\sss\scriptscriptstyle 
\newcommand\sspl{{\scriptscriptstyle+}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

$a_0\epsilon_0+b_0$ % subscripts in \scriptstyle

$a_{\sss +}\epsilon_{\sss +}+b_\sspl$ % subscripts in \scriptscriptstyle

$a_{+}\epsilon_{+}+b_{+}$ % subscripts in \scriptstyle

\end{document}


Whereas the other response is what I was asking, yours looks better for more purposes. For instance, your's solution looks better for using $+$ as a label: compare \mathfrak{h} = \mathfrak{h}_{0} + \mathfrak{h}_{\sss +} against \mathfrak{h} = \mathfrak{h}_0 + \mathfrak{h}_\subplus. Thanks.
